# Is it possible to add a custom SDK for iOS applications if the application is created on ionic and capacitor?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, capacitor

Project on ionic and capacitor

I want to add an sdk to the iOS platform. Then I do pod install. Everything is ok up to this point. And when I launch the application on iOS, this error comes out and does not allow the application to start

```
dyld[9368]: Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginManager)
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2EECAC5E-F2D8-4E30-860C-9E9B2DE814FA/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor'
  Expected in: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2EECAC5E-F2D8-4E30-860C-9E9B2DE814FA/App.app/Frameworks/Cordova.framework/Cordova'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHsze.jpg)

If anyone is interested, then I added this SDK https://github.com/btsdigital/identification-sdk

How to solve this error? I will be grateful for every answer!

I tried to add Cordova to the ios project via "pod 'Cordova'" but it didn't work

I tried to figure out the Linked Libraries, but other errors have already come out there, I didn't understand them and returned them as it was

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apple silicon try this:

```
$ sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

go to ios folder then run

```
$ arch -x86_64 pod install
```